# I am using mvvm and I want to pass an id through intent to my retrofit function in my paging source class

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mvvm, android-paging

I want to pass an id which is coming from intent to my retrofit function in paging source class which is part of android jet pack paging. someone please tell me how can I do this. A detail help would be appreciated.
Paging Source Class

```
class CollectionDetailSource(
    private val apiInterface: ApiInterface,
    private val collectionId: String,
) : PagingSource<Int, Photo>() {
    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, Photo>): Int? = state.anchorPosition

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Photo> {
        val page = params.key ?: 1
        val response =
            apiInterface.getCollectionPhotos("the id which i want to pass from intent", API_KEY, page, params.loadSize)
        return try {
            val photos = response.body()!!
            LoadResult.Page(
                data = photos,
                prevKey = if (page == 1) null else page - 1,
                nextKey = if (photos.isEmpty()) null else page + 1
            )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            LoadResult.Error(e)
        }
    }

}
```

View Model

```
class CollectionDetailViewModel() : ViewModel() {
    constructor(collectionId: String) : this()

    private var apiInterface: ApiInterface = retrofit
    private fun getCollectionPhotos(collectionId: String) =
        Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(pageSize = 30,
                maxSize = 100,
                enablePlaceholders = false)
        ){
            CollectionDetailSource(apiInterface,collectionId)
        }.flow
    val latestCollectionPhotos = getCollectionPhotos(this.toString()).cachedIn(viewModelScope).asLiveData()
}
```

Comment: What's the issue with your current code?

Comment: @MalikBilal it does not show anything

Comment: @MalikBilal in CollectionDetailSource class I to pass collection id which is coming through intent, how can I do it?